# how to work with dictionary in maya python

Tags: python, maya

i try to learn Dictionary on maya python.

i want to record the rotations from some objects, and i will use it later
its working to record the value, but its always give me 'none' answer when i call the dictionary

```
import maya.cmds as cmds

myDic = {}

def test():
    mods = cmds.getModifiers()
    SELlis = cmds.ls(sl = 1)

    a = 0
    b = 1

    if mods == 4:
        for obj in SELlis:
            myDic[obj] = cmds.getAttr(obj+'.rotate')

    else :
        for obj in SELlis:
            if obj in myDic:
                print myDic.get(obj)

            else :
                print 'none'
   test()
```

Thanks

Comment: What's the problem/question?

Comment: sorry i forgot to explain the question, it fix nowthanks

Comment: I suppose the last 'test()' should have no indetation? Because this would cause an infinite recoursion.

Comment: How exactly do you execute the script?

Comment: Hi Haggi, thanks for replying, i drag the script into mayas button tools, so it would be come as a button. i use ctrl + left mouse to click that button to record the value of the objects, and left mouse click to call the value

Answer (score 0):

sorry my fault, i create 'myDic = {}' at the very beginning, so every time i push the button it will reset 'myDic' as none

```
import maya.cmds as cmds
def test():
    global myDic
    mods = cmds.getModifiers()
    SELlis = cmds.ls(sl = 1)

    if mods == 4:
        myDic = {}
        for obj in SELlis:
            myDic[obj] = cmds.getAttr(obj+'.rotate')

    else :
        for obj in SELlis:
            if obj in myDic:
                print myDic.get(obj)

            else :
                print 'none'
test()
```

Comment: So it works now? I suppose not because you now create the myDic in function local scope and it will be deleted if the function is finished.

Comment: Hi Haggi, no its not deleted yet, because its a button, and myDic will be on the memmory until the function was finished (when i clouse the program) so i could call it again and again... btw thanks Haggi

Comment: That's really interesting. For me this does not work at all, I get an `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'myDic' referenced before assignment` error. The reason is simple: Your myDic is created in the scope of the `if mods == 4:` condition and is thrown away as soon as it reached the `else:`. So if it works for you, then something really strange is happening on your side ;)

Comment: Hi Haggi, oh yes, sorry i accidentally remove the 'global myDic'... hope it works now :)